# Considering quantity which a random variable depends on as own random variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-expectation, conditional-probability, independence

Let us consider a random variable $X^{(n)}$ which depends on a deterministic quantity $n$.
Then $P(X^{(n)}=x)=f(x,n).$

Now let us set the $n$ to random variable $N$. 
Can one say generally that $P(X^{(N)}=x|N=n)=f(n)$?
Which conditions have to be fulfilled for that?

I saw it a few times that some authors write $P(X^{(N)}=x)=f(x,N)$. That does not make sense imo as probability is deterministic, not random. So I thought maybe they mean $P(X^{(N)}=x|N)=f(N)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It feels like what you makes sense. $P(X^{(N)}=x)=f(N)$ is valid, and in this statement $N$ is random, so $f(N)$ is some random density (but I think it would be better still to write $f(x,N)$). However if you condition on a particular setting of $N$ it becomes a deterministic density function, so that you now arrive at, $P(X^{(N)}=x|N=n)=f(n)$ (and I would still prefer to write $f(x,n))$. The conditioning on a particular setting of $N$ is important.

> probability is deterministic, not random

This is not a very clear statement. The evaluation of a probability mass function at a particular point is not random, but a probability measure is meant to help encode a sense of randomness via the random variable you define.

> So I thought maybe they mean $P(X(N)=x|N)=f(N)$.

This does not make sense to me. As I said before you need to condition on an actual value. You need to be *given* a value, hence you should condition at $N= n $. A event must have occurred.

I think it could be insightful to understand the difference between the parameterisation of a density, and its density dummy variable used to define the density. What is a common example is something like: $\mathcal{N}(x;\mu,\sigma^2)$, where $x$ is density variable, and the parameterisation are non-random quantities. Under your notation this could be expressed as, $P(X^{(\mu,\sigma^2)}\leq x) = \int_{-\infty}^x \mathcal{N}(x;\mu,\sigma^2) dx$, where $X\sim\mathcal{N}(x;\mu,\sigma^2)$,  since remember the probability for a continuous R.V. requires an integration over the pdf.

Comment: But is $P(X^{(N)}=x\mid N=n)=P(X^{(n)}=x)$ always valid?? For example for $X^{(N)}:=\sum_{i=1}^N X_i$ with $X_i$ being iid you need independence of the $X_i$ and $N$ such that $E[\sum_{i=1}^N X_i\mid N=n]=E[\sum_{i=1}^n X_i]$.

Comment: That's how I believe the conditional works though. $N$ and $X$ don't have to be independent. If they are not then the it will manifest in the joint distribution so that $P(X,N)\neq P(X)P(N)$. Regardless of this you can still use the product rule on that joint so that, $P(X,N) = P(X|N)P(N)$. Then you can sample an n from $P(N)$ and pass through to the likelihood function which will evaluate as $P(X|N=n)$.